# Replacing with x and y involving trigonometry.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$x = a \text{ cosec }\theta$

$y = b\cot\theta$

I am asked to replace $\text{ cosec }\theta$ and $\cot\theta$ by x and y while also connecting the two terms using a trigonometrical identity.

What I was able to perform.

$x^2 = a^2\text{ cosec}^2θ$

$y^2 = b^2\cot^2θ$

Given that $\cot^2θ + 1 = \text{ cosec}^2θ  $

Comment: You may want to format your posts with MathJax. Here' some tips: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formulae you have and do the following:
$$
1 = \mathrm{cosec}^{2}\theta - \mathrm{cot}^{2}\theta = \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}.
$$
The equation you get is $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} = 1$, which represents a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

You have $cosec^2 \theta = \frac{x^2}{a^2}$and $cot^2 \theta =\frac {y^2}{b^2}$

Using the trigonometric identity:

$\frac{x^2}{a^2} -\frac{ y^2}{b^2 }= 1$